# Group the validation message shown visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, validation-rule, error-messages

I have visualforce page which has some validation. So the problem certain error messages comes in from validation rule(9 in nos), certain validations are done in the apex class of the visualforce page. The requirement is to show the validation messages in group at one go if it fails any condition? Any idea?

Comment: If you get control over all the error messages, then you could probably create a string variable and append each error message by a separator and display in vf page.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for [`apex:pageMessages`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_pageMessages.htm). This component displays all messages that were generated for all components on the current page, presented using the Salesforce styling.